# SIMPLIS - Pop trigger and evolve pop trigger

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I am new on SIMPLIS but it appears to be the best simulations tool for smps.

I just have a question : What the difference between this two POP trigger ?

[image]

[image]

I found it on the RICHTEK [Website](https://www.richtek.com/Design%20Support/Technical%20Document/AN028?sc_lang=en). But this is not the first time that I see it...

Thank you,

Comment: I believe these are just two different symbols of the same function, instructing the software when transitions occur.