# A steady-state DC model of FLyback in CCM with two outputs (multiple outputs)

Tags: flyback, steady-state

I tried to post it in a "normal" form but Stack blocks it, so put the question as figures.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you exactly want to determine? Is it the dc transfer characteristic that you want from this dual-output flyback? If this is the case, I would recommend you use the PWM switch model with a 2-output transformer simplified model and by applying volt-second balance, you should get there quite quickly.

Comment: @VerbalKint The purpouse is to obtain a steady-state DC model of the Flyback converter. In a book "Fundamentals of Power Electronics" written by Erickson and Maksimovic in the CHapter 3 introduced a procedure of deriving them. This is quite similar procedure like during deriving small-signal models. 


The PWM switch averaging is one of the techniques used to derive this model. Here I use a simple equation approach. I trust that it will be faster, but for educational reasons and "developing intuition" I decided to do it in the classic form.

Comment: I don't see any question here, just a bunch of images? Surely this will never be useful to anyone else in its present form (e.g. searchable)...

Comment: @TimWilliams I know, Stack recognized my post as spam. I put a lot of effort to write it...

Answer (score 3):

Using the PWM switch model is quite straightforward to obtain the dc transfer characteristic of this 2-output flyback converter operated in continuous conduction time or CCM:

[image]

Then launch SPICE for a dc operating point analysis. Once you have the bias points, redraw the circuit in a more friendly form:

[image]

and solve simple equations to determine the two dc output voltages.

Comment: Did you see this question? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/689385/simplis-buck-cm-from-c-basso-website  and this one https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/689359/simplis-pop-trigger-and-evolve-pop-trigger